# Calculate total price script not working

Tags: javascript, calculated-field, subtotal

I want to calculate the total price and display the subtotal at the bottom of the form, but it's not working and I don't know why.

The subtotal should be showing the total price after substraction or addition of the elements "prijsvolwassenen", "prijskinderen", "prijspeuters" and "prijskamertype"

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/B6mPP/)

this is my script

```
$(document).ready(function calculatePrice(formclear) {

 //Get selected data  
var elt = document.getElementById("prijsvolwassenen");
var volwassenen = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

var elt = document.getElementById("prijskinderen");
var kinderen = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

var elt = document.getElementById("prijspeuters");
var peuters = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

var elt = document.getElementById("prijskamertype");
var kamertype = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

//convert data to integers
volwassenen = parseInt(volwassenen);
kinderen = parseInt(kinderen);
peuters = parseInt(peuters);
kamertype = parseInt(kamertype);

//calculate total value  
var total = volwassenen+kinderen+peuters+kamertype; 

//print value to  PicExtPrice 
document.getElementById("PicExtPrice").value=total;

}
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
   <form name="formclear" action="" method="post" id="bootstrap-frm">   
 <label>
    <span>Volwassenen :</span>
        <select class="autowidthselect" name="prijsvolwassenen" onChange="calculatePrice()" id="prijsvolwassenen">
            <option value="-50">1</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="0">2</option>
            <option value="50">3</option>
            <option value="100">4</option>
            <option value="150">5</option>
            <option value="200">6</option>
            <option value="250">7</option>
            <option value="300">8</option>
    </select>
</label>  

<label>
    <span>Kinderen (4-12 jr) :</span>
        <select class="autowidthselect" name="prijskinderen" onChange="calculatePrice()" id="prijskinderen">
            <option value="-50">0</option>
            <option value="-25">1</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="0">2</option>
            <option value="25">3</option>
            <option value="50">4</option>
            <option value="75">5</option>
            <option value="100">6</option>
            <option value="125">7</option>
        </select>
</label>

<label>
    <span>Kinderen (0-3 jr) :</span>
        <select class="autowidthselect" name="prijspeuters" onChange="calculatePrice()" id="prijspeuters">
            <option selected="selected" value="0">0</option>
            <option value="15">1</option>
            <option value="30">2</option>
            <option value="45">3</option>
            <option value="60">4</option>
            <option value="75">5</option>
            <option value="90">6</option>
            <option value="105">7</option>
        </select>
</label>

<label>
    <span> Kamertype :</span>
        <select class="autowidthselect" name="prijskamertype" onChange="calculatePrice()" id="prijskamertype">
            <option selected="selected" value="selecteer kamertype">Selecteer kamertype</option>
            <option value="295">Kraaiennest</option>
            <option value="395">Kajuit</option>
            <option value="495">Kapiteinshut</option>
        </select>
</label>

<label>
    <button type="button" onclick="calculatePrice()">Calculate</button>
</label>

<label>
    <span>Subtotaal: </span>
        <input id="PicExtPrice" type="text" size="10"/>
</label>

 </form>
```

Comment: If you check your browser console, you'll see this error message: `Uncaught ReferenceError: calculatePrice is not defined`.

Comment: This part is `jQuery` and it's been used in a wrong way: `$(document).ready(`. You don't use `jQuery` anywhere in your code, so why did you try to use this? If you intended to use `jQuery`, you should reference the library.

Comment: I hope you check prices on the server too, because some virtual shop thieves know Javascript.

Comment: @Marieke Hoog: read all my answer and look at the souce code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually mixing up things there. You tried to use `document ready` that's part of the `jQuery` library (which you're not loading nor using anywhere in your code), when actually you just needed to declare a function.

This script should work for you:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function calculatePrice() {
            //Get selected data  
            var elt = document.getElementById("prijsvolwassenen");
            var volwassenen = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;
            var elt = document.getElementById("prijskinderen");
            var kinderen = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;
            var elt = document.getElementById("prijspeuters");
            var peuters = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;
            var elt = document.getElementById("prijskamertype");
            var kamertype = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

            //convert data to integers
            volwassenen = parseInt(volwassenen);
            kinderen = parseInt(kinderen);
            peuters = parseInt(peuters);
            kamertype = parseInt(kamertype);

            //calculate total value  
            var total = volwassenen + kinderen + peuters + kamertype;

            //print value to  PicExtPrice 
            document.getElementById("PicExtPrice").value = total;
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B6mPP/4/)

Comment: Tip: You should check if what's being selected are numbers before trying to sum them up.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a simple syntax error.
At the end of your code, you have

```
}
}
```

The first `}` closes the function, but the second `}` is causing an error. Try replacing it with a `)` to close the ready function.

Also, I noticed that you didn't reference jQuery, so that is also causing an error. In the left, change the text-box that says "No-Library (pure JS)" to a version of jQuery.

Comment: ...and then get into the habit of checking your browsers console for trivial errors like this before posting to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @MariekeHoog: Are there any errors in your console?

Comment: Why are people actually upvoting this answer? It doesn't solve the problem and it's totally wrong.

Comment: @RichieHindle yes, that is important to mention. The console is a programmer's best friend, and it is a huge time saver.

Answer (score 0):

You should make more use of jQuery when referencing it (which you forgot to do in your fiddle by the way). What I think you want to achieve is something like this:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/B6mPP/5/)**

**HTML**

```
<form name="formclear" action="" method="post" id="bootstrap-frm">
    <label> <span>Volwassenen :</span>

        <select class="autowidthselect" name="prijsvolwassenen" id="prijsvolwassenen">
            <option value="-50">1</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="0">2</option>
            <option value="50">3</option>
            <option value="100">4</option>
            <option value="150">5</option>
            <option value="200">6</option>
            <option value="250">7</option>
            <option value="300">8</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <label> <span>Kinderen (4-12 jr) :</span>

        <select class="autowidthselect" name="prijskinderen" id="prijskinderen">
            <option value="-50">0</option>
            <option value="-25">1</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="0">2</option>
            <option value="25">3</option>
            <option value="50">4</option>
            <option value="75">5</option>
            <option value="100">6</option>
            <option value="125">7</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <label> <span>Kinderen (0-3 jr) :</span>

        <select class="autowidthselect" name="prijspeuters" id="prijspeuters">
            <option selected="selected" value="0">0</option>
            <option value="15">1</option>
            <option value="30">2</option>
            <option value="45">3</option>
            <option value="60">4</option>
            <option value="75">5</option>
            <option value="90">6</option>
            <option value="105">7</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <label> <span> Kamertype :</span>

        <select class="autowidthselect" name="prijskamertype" id="prijskamertype">
            <option selected="selected" value="selecteer kamertype">Selecteer kamertype</option>
            <option value="295">Kraaiennest</option>
            <option value="395">Kajuit</option>
            <option value="495">Kapiteinshut</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <label> <span>Subtotaal: </span>

        <input id="PicExtPrice" type="text" size="10" />
    </label>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("select").on("change", function () {
        CalculatePrice();
    });
    $("#CalculatePrice").on("click", function () {
        CalculatePrice();
    });
});

function CalculatePrice() 
{
    var pv = parseInt($("#prijsvolwassenen").val(), 10);
    var pk = parseInt($("#prijskinderen").val(), 10);
    var pp = parseInt($("#prijspeuters").val(), 10);
    var pkt = parseInt($("#prijskamertype").val(), 10);

    if (!isNaN(pkt))
        $("#PicExtPrice").val(pv+pk+pp+pkt);
}
```

EDIT: Updated answer using vanilla JS:
Make your JS like this:

**JS**

```
function calculatePrice() {
            //Get selected data  
            var elt = document.getElementById("prijsvolwassenen");
            var volwassenen = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

            var elt = document.getElementById("prijskinderen");
            var kinderen = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

            var elt = document.getElementById("prijspeuters");
            var peuters = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

            var elt = document.getElementById("prijskamertype");
            var kamertype = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

            //convert data to integers
            volwassenen = parseInt(volwassenen);
            kinderen = parseInt(kinderen);
            peuters = parseInt(peuters);
            kamertype = parseInt(kamertype);

            //check if each value is a number and calculate total value
            if (!isNaN(volwassenen) && !isNaN(kinderen) && !isNaN(peuters) && !isNaN(kamertype)) {
                var total = volwassenen + kinderen + peuters + kamertype;

                //print value to  PicExtPrice 
                document.getElementById("PicExtPrice").value = total;
            }
        }
```

**[VANILLA FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/B6mPP/8/)**

Comment: It's great to use `jQuery` but for this question it's totally useless. The OP wrote everything using `Vanilla Javascript`, apart from the mistake declaring the function. It should stay as it is, because it works (after fixing the small issue).

Comment: @MelanciaUK True, but the tag had jQuery, therefor a jQuery answer. I've added a vanilla answer which should work.

Comment: @MelanciaUK: and the OP is using this in his code: $(document).ready()

Comment: Using in the wrong way. A mistake when declaring a simple function. I think this is pretty clear: `$(document).ready(function calculatePrice(formclear)`. And there's not a single other use of `jQuery` in the code.

Answer (score -1):

More DRY code http://jsfiddle.net/B6mPP/6/

```
$(function(){
    var fields = $('#prijsvolwassenen,#prijskinderen,#prijspeuters,#prijskamertype'), 
        total = $('#PicExtPrice');

    function calculateTotal(){
        var sum = 0;
        fields.each(function(){
            var value = parseInt($(this).val());
            value == value && (sum += value);
        })
        total.val(sum);            
    };

    fields.change(calculateTotal);
    $('#calculate').click(calculateTotal);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

> - **demo:** https://so.lucafilosofi.com/calculate-total-price-script-not-working/

```
$(function(){
    $('.autowidthselect').on('change', function(){
        calculatePrice();    
    });

    $('button').on('click', function(){
        calculatePrice();
        return false;
    });

    function calculatePrice() {
        var total = 0;
        $('.autowidthselect').each(function(){
            total += !isNaN(this.value) ? parseInt(this.value) : 0;
        });
        $("#PicExtPrice").val(total);
    }
});
```

## vanila javascript fix

> - http://jsfiddle.net/B6mPP/10/